# What is the benefits of mocking the dependencies in unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am working on unit testing stuffs for my controller and service layers(C#,MVC). And I am using Moq dll for mocking the real/dependency objects in unit testing.

But I am little bit confuse regarding mocking the dependencies or real objects. Lets take a example of below unit test method :-

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldReturnDtosWhenCustomersFound_GetCustomers ()
{
    // Arrrange 
    var name = "ricky";
    var description = "this is the test";

    // setup mocked dal to return list of customers
    // when name and description passed to GetCustomers method
    _customerDalMock.Setup(d => d.GetCustomers(name, description)).Returns(_customerList);

    // Act
    List<CustomerDto> actual = _CustomerService.GetCustomers(name, description);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.IsTrue(actual.Any());

    // verify all setups of mocked dal were called by service
    _customerDalMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

In the above unit test method I am mocking the GetCustomers method and returning a customer list. Which is already defined. And looks like below:

```
List<Customer> _customerList = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { CustomerID = 1, Name="Mariya",Description="description"},
    new Customer { CustomerID = 2, Name="Soniya",Description="des"},
    new Customer { CustomerID = 3, Name="Bill",Description="my desc"},
    new Customer { CustomerID = 4, Name="jay",Description="test"},
};
```

And lets have a look on the Assertion of Customer mocked object and actual object Assertion :-

```
Assert.AreEqual(_customer.CustomerID, actual.CustomerID);
Assert.AreEqual(_customer.Name, actual.Name);
Assert.AreEqual(_customer.Description, actual.Description);
```

But here I am not understanding that it(above unit test) always work fine. Means we are just testing(in Assertion) which we passed or which we are returning(in mocking object). And we know that the real/actual object will always return which list or object that we passed.

So what is the meaning of doing unit testing or mocking here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The true purpose of mocking is to achieve true isolation.

Say you have a `CustomerService` class, that depends on a `CustomerRepository`. You write a few unit tests covering the features provided by `CustomerService`. They all pass.

A month later, a few changes were made, and suddenly your `CustomerServices` unit tests start failing - and you need to find where the problem is.

So you assume:

> Because a unit test that tests `CustomerServices` is failing, the problem must be in that class!!

Right? Wrong! The problem could be either in `CustomerServices` or in any of its depencies, i.e., `CustomerRepository`. If any of its dependencies fail, chances are the class under test will fail too.

Now picture a huge chain of dependencies: `A` depends on `B`, `B` depends on `C`, ... `Y` depends on `Z`. If a fault is introduced in `Z`, *all* your unit tests will fail.

And that's why you need to isolate the class under test from its dependencies (may it be a domain object, a database connection, file resources, etc). You want to test a *unit*.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is too simplistic to show off the real benefit of mocking. That's because your logic under test isn't really doing much beyond returning some data.

But imagine as an example that your logic did something based on wall clock time, say scheduled some process every hour. In a situation like that, mocking the time source lets you actually unit test such logic so that your test doesn't have to run for hours, waiting for the time to pass.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what already been said:

We can have classes without dependencies. And the only thing we have is unit testing without mocks and stubs.

When we have dependencies there are several kinds of them:

- Service that our class uses mostly in a 'fire and forget' way, i.e. services that do not affect control flow of the consuming code.

We can mock these (and all other kinds) services to test they were called correctly (integration testing) or simply  for injecting as they could be required by our code.

- Two Way Services that provide result but do not have an internal
  state and do not affect the state of the system. They can be dubbed complex data transformations.

By mocking these services you can test you expectations about code behavior for different variants of service implementation without need to heave all of them.

- Services which affect the state of the system or depend on real world
  phenomena or something out of your control. '@500 - Internal Server Error' gave a good example of the time service.

With mocking you can let the time flow at the speed (and direction) whatever is needed.
 Another example is working with DB. When unit testing it is usually desirable not to change DB  state what is not true about functional test. For such kind of services 'isolation' is the main (but not the only) motivation for mocking.

- Services with internal state your code depends on.

Consider Entity Framework:
When `SaveChanges()` is called, many things happen behind the scene. EF detects changes and fixups navigation properties. Also EF won't allow you to add several entities with the same key.
Evidently, it can be very difficult to mock the behavior and the complexity of such dependencies...but usually you have not if they are designed well. If you heavily rely on the functionality some component provides you hardly will be able to substitute this dependency. What is probably needed is isolation again. You don't want to leave traces when testing, thus butter approach is to tell EF not to use real DB. Yes, dependency means more than a mere interface. More often it is not the methods signatures but the contract for expected behavior. For instance `IDbConnection` has `Open()` and `Close()` methods what implies certain sequence of calls.

Sure, it is not strict classification. Better to treat it as extremes.

@dcastro writes: `You want to test a unit.` Yet the statement doesn't answer the question whether you should.
Lets not discount integration tests. Sometimes knowing that some composite part of the system has a failure is ok.
As to example with the chain of dependencies given by @dcastro we can try to find the place where the bag is likely to by:

Assume, `Z` is a final dependency. We create unit tests without mocks for it. All boundary conditions are known. 100% coverage is a must here. After that we say that Z works correctly. And if `Z` fails our unit tests must indicate it.
The analogue comes from engineering. Nobody tests each screw and bolt when building a plane.
Statistic methods are used to prove with some certainty that factory producing the details works fine.

On the other hand, for very critical parts of your system it is reasonable to spend time and mock complex behavior of the dependency. Yes, the more complex it is the less maintainable tests are going to be. And here I'd rather call them as the specification checks.
Yes your api and tests both can be wrong but code review and other forms of testing can assure the correctness of the code to some degree. And as soon as these tests fail after some changes are made you either need to change specs and corresponding tests or find the bug and cover the case with the test.

I highly recommend you watching Roy's videos:  http://youtube.com/watch?v=fAb_OnooCsQ

Answer (score 0):

In this very case mocking allowed you to fake a database connection, so that you can run a test in place and in-memory, without relying on any additional resource, i.e. the database. This tests asserts that, when a service is called, a corresponded method of DAL is called.

However the later asserts of the list and the values in list aren't necessary. As you correctly noticed you just asserting that the values you "mocked" are returned. This would be useful within the mocking framework itself, to assert that the mocking methods behave as expected. But in your code is is just excess.

In general case, mocking allow one to:

- Test behaviour (when something happens, then a particular method is executed)
- Fake resources (for example, email servers, web servers, HTTP API request/response, database)

In contrast, unit-tests without mocking usually allow you to test the state. That is, you can detect a change in a state of an object, when a particular method was called.

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers assume that mocking has some value, and then they proceed to explain what that value supposedly is.

For the sake of future generations that might arrive at this question looking to satisfy their philosophical objections on the issue, here is a dissenting opinion:

Mocking, despite being a nifty trick, should be avoided at (almost) all costs.

When you mock a dependency of your code-under-test, you are ***by definition*** making two kinds of assumptions:

- Assumptions about the behavior of the dependency
- Assumptions about the inner workings of your code-under-test

It can be argued that the assumptions about the behavior of the dependency are innocent because they are simply a stipulation of how the real dependency should behave according to some requirements or specification document. I would be willing to accept this, with the footnote that they are still assumptions, and whenever you make assumptions you are living your life dangerously.

Now, what ***cannot*** be argued is that the assumptions you are making about the inner workings of your code-under-test are essentially turning your test into a white-box test: the mock expects the code-under-test to issue specific calls to its dependencies, with specific parameters, and as the mock returns specific results, the code-under-test is expected to behave in specific ways.

White-box testing might be suitable if you are building high criticality (aerospace grade) software, where the goal is to leave absolutely nothing to chance, and cost is not a concern. It is orders of magnitude more labor intensive than black-box testing, so it is immensely expensive, and it is a complete overkill for commercial software, where the goal is simply to meet the requirements, not to ensure that every single bit in memory has some exact expected value at any given moment.

White-box testing is labor intensive because it renders tests extremely fragile: every single time you modify the code-under-test, even if the modification is not in response to a change in requirements, you will have to go modify every single mock you have written to test that code. That is an insanely high maintenance level.

How to avoid mocks and black-box testing

- Use fakes instead of mocks

  - For an explanation of what the difference is, you can read this article by Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html but to give you an example, an in-memory database can be used as fake in place of a full-blown RDBMS. (Note how fakes are a lot less fake than mocks.)
  - Fakes will give you the same amount of isolation as mocks would, but without all the risky and costly assumptions, and most importantly, without all the fragility.
- Do integration testing instead of unit testing

  - Using the fakes whenever possible, of course.

For a longer article with my thoughts on the subject, see https://blog.michael.gr/2021/12/white-box-vs-black-box-testing.html