# Unit Test an ApiController's fetching of an entity with autoinclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a many to many relationship in my Entities and am trying to test my ApiController to give me the correct results. I have a check to determine if the Id given, returns the proper result. In this entity there's an ICollection list and I'm trying to have AutoInclude fetch it's results.

In my Unit Tests I setup the models required and create the objects manually. However when I fetch the object I want, the AutoInclude property fails and I get a null from my Repository.

Actual usage of the controller works, but with Unit Testing it doesn't. I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong here.

My code:

**Unit Test**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdateDashboardScreen_OkResult()
    {
        // Arrange
        _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(
            p => p.Repository<DashboardScreen>().Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DashboardScreen, bool>>>()))
            .Returns(_listOfDashboardScreens.Find(a => a.Id.Equals(_testDashboardScreen1.Id)));

        _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(p => p.UserRepository().GetAllActive(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>()))
            .Returns(_listOfUsers);

        var dto = new DashboardScreenDto
        {
            Id = _testDashboardScreen1.Id,
            Title = _testDashboardScreen1.Title,
            DataType = (int) _testDashboardScreen1.DataType,
            Type = (int) _testDashboardScreen1.Type,
            Visible = _testDashboardScreen1.Visible,
            IsRemoved = _testDashboardScreen1.IsRemoved,
            Users = new List<string> {_testUser.Id}
        };

        // Act
        var actionResult = _dashboardScreenController.PostUpdatedScreen(dto);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof (OkResult));
        _unitOfWorkMock.Verify(a => a.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
```

**Entity**

```
public class DashboardScreen : BaseEntity
{
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, 
        ErrorMessage = "Title can not be longer than 100 characters.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\w{0,22}(\s|\b))+$", 
        ErrorMessage = "A word may not be longer than 22 characters.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(DashboardType))]
    public DashboardType Type { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(DashboardDataType))]
    public DashboardDataType DataType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> AllocatedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
// TODO: Fix unit tests so that the include works. Removing the include here makes the Unit Tests succeed.
var original = _uow.Repository<DashboardScreen>().Get(t => t.Id == slDto.Id, "AllocatedUsers");
if (original == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: These is where you can benefit from adding service layer to your app, so you're unit testing services rather than controller actions....

Comment: What do you mean? This controller is an ApiController. Accessible via URL. How would you enter a Service into this picture? Also I make use of the Repository and UnitOfWork patterns. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Good example can be found in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783772/what-is-the-benefits-of-mocking-the-dependencies-in-unit-testing